# Failed to process JSON data in JQuery form Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, html, css, json, spring-mvc

I need JQuery code to get JSON data from Spring MVC Controller and process it then diplay the data in html.

My Spring MVC Controller name: ProductInfo passing value:today

http://localhost:8080/Cart/ProductInfo/today

It returns the following JSON data

```
[{"productImage":null,"productId":"flower","productName":"rose","productPrice":23.0,"productCategory":"today"},{"productImage":null,"productId":"lotus","productName":"rose","productPrice":23.0,"productCategory":"today"}]
```

I want a JQuery Code  to get the data using jQuery and Process it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var serverInfo = '[{"productImage":null,"productId":"flower","productName":"rose","productPrice":23.0,"productCategory":"today"},{"productImage":null,"productId":"lotus","productName":"rose","productPrice":23.0,"productCategory":"today"}]'
,   parsedInfo = JSON.parse(serverInfo)
,   list = $("#productList")
,   newElements = ''
,   newList = '';

$.each( parsedInfo, function( key, value ) {
    newList = '<li><ul>';

  newElements = '<li> Product Id: ' + value.productId + '</li><br />';
  newElements += '<li> Product Name: ' + value.productName + '</li><br />';
  newElements += '<li> Product Price: ' + value.productPrice + '</li><br />';
  newElements += '<li> Product Category: ' + value.productCategory + '</li><br />';

  newList += newElements;
  newList += '</li></ul>';

  list.append(newList);
});
```

See
https://jsfiddle.net/4xny1h18/

And regarding getting the info from the server, see if you can try

```
$.get( "Cart/ProductInfo/today", function( data ) {
    // data would be the JSON you wrote.
});
```

Comment: Thanks mrifon, and  i need the serverInfo value form that url i mentioned before. can u help me to get the JSON data form that URl.